# How to match 4 or 5 digit number in the following?

Tags: regex, perl

How to match the number in the below string?

```
pe01058pr04
pe1234pr03
```

We may get 4 digit or 5 digit as show above.

I tried the below regex:

```
.*([0-9]{4,5}).*
```

But it matches only 4 digits.

I need 5 digit to be matched for "pe01058pr04" --> 01058

I need 4 digit to be matched for "pe1234pr03" --> 1234

Comment: Just remove `.*` from your regex.

Comment: If your regex needs to match the full string, `[^\d]+(\d{4,5}).*` is also an option

Comment: What do you want to do if there are 6 digits in a row?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `\d{4,5}` to match either 4 or 5 digits.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X1M5GT/1)**

Also, your regex does match all five and four digits like you want in group1. [See this](https://regex101.com/r/X1M5GT/2) But why don't you simply use `\d{4,5}` like I suggested above?a

Comment: .*(\d{4,5}).*
dosent work,
it only match 1058 in the string : pe01058pr04

Comment: This won't work because `.*` in your regex is greedy and will consume as much as it can and hence will consume the first number and will only give you last match. You can use non-greedy version to get two matches with this regex `.*?(\d{4,5}).*?` but why don't you simply get digits using `\d{4,5}` ?

Comment: `.*?(\d{4,5}).*?` -- this worked for me. Thank you !

Comment: @kaushikkm: Yes, non-greedy pattern will work as then `.*?` will just as less as possible but if you see even your regex works `.([0-9]{4,5}).` to give you your intended matches in group1. But best would be to use `\d{4,5}`

Comment: Using `.*?` in a pattern for reasons other than optimizations is a red flag. Using two in the same pattern is a huge red flag. These will rarely work as intended. `(?<\d)\d{4,5}` or `(?<\d)\d{4,5}(?!\d)` (depending on how you want to handle 6 digits) is far safer.

Answer (score 1):

```
my ($first_sequence_of_digits) = $string =~ /(\d+)/;
```